# GAC_MSIL and Shell Extensions

Tags: c#, .net, shell, dll, gac-msil

I've trying to develop while also creating a COM .DLL for my shell icon overlay and context stuff, so i do some search on the tool to make this happens, then i found SharpShell, the shell extension helper tool.

I've been using sharpshell to create an example .DLL, once its generated, i used their "Server Manager" to automatically helps register my .DLL to the registry and the server is loaded properly.

On the Registry, I've seen them registered properly, but i don't see any change in my UI. So i tried to download "Shell Ext Viewer - Shexview - 64 Bit. "
After i opened my shell lists, i saw my Dll was registered there, but they are reading my .DLL files in C:\Windows\Assembly\GAC_MSIL\ folder.
So i tried browsing them in in my Explorer, but i find out that i dont have GAC Assembly.

I further checked articles for help, i found out that they're .nEt extensions, and i also checked my .NET, all of the .NETs from 4.0 are installed properly, but i dont have GAC_MSIL in my assembly. What should i do in order to tell my Shell to open my dll file into a correct file? is there any a way from visual studio where can i register my Dll and server to a specified folder, instead of GAC_MSIL folder, because i am missing it?

Thank you, and i would really appreciate your help !

Comment: You are not missing that folder, you just can't see it.  You discovered why there are so many stern warnings to never use .NET to write shell extensions.  And why Microsoft refuses to support it.  It suffers strongly from the "what if two extensions do this?" problem.  Completely undiagnosable.  You have another extension installed on your machine and it demanded that it needs CLR v2.  And got it.  You need v4, you lose.

Comment: Thank you, but in order for my dll to be working, i do need to put my shell dll there. Is there any way to do it? Or its better to change my dll source path to any other place?

Answer (score 1):

There are some limitations for OverlayIcons. You have only 15 slots for OverlayIcons. If you have Dropbox or Google Drive installed (or Subversion) > you have already lost, because no slots are available anymore.

But there some way to make bigger Priority for your ShellExtensions. Read here more https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell/issues/93

Comment: Answers with just a link are not good answers as they become totally worthless when the 3rd-party site is down or gone. At least briefly line-out how the linked answer works.